# Expected foo.rb to define Foo - in my case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Fellas! I've run into the

```
Expected foo.rb to define Foo
```

problem.
I can't figure out what the hell is the solution. I have run the rails console and asked for that model to have a more detailed errore code. I got this:

```
irb(main):002:0> c = Card_positions.find(1)
NameError: uninitialized constant Card_positions
        from (irb):2
        from C:/Programozas/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/
             rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
        from C:/Programozas/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/
             rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from C:/Programozas/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/
             rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Programozas/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_req
             uire.rb:59:in `require'
        from C:/Programozas/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_req
             uire.rb:59:in `rescue in require'
        from C:/Programozas/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_req
             uire.rb:35:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Solution ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a table named `card_positions`, you should be doing `CardPosition.find(1)`.

Comment: BANG!! Allways the basics... Tx